# how can i take screenshot with a button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screenshot

I want to develop a simple app that can take screenshot of current screen by a button. This code run successfully but when i press capture button then it not works and return error.

```js
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    captureScreen({
      format: "jpg",
      quality: 0.8
    })
    .then(
      uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
      error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    );
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native SnapShot!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={captureScreen.bind(this)}
          title="capture"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Capture"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you capturing screenshot in render? I think you need to move your screenshot snippet to a separate function.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native SnapShot!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            captureScreen({
              format: "jpg",
              quality: 0.8
            })
            .then(
              uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
              error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
            );
          }}
          title="capture"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Capture"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this code works bt i didn't find any screenshot image in my android emulator gallery.
how can i save it to storage?